# How to write current and future year in link?

Tags: php, jquery

I have some links that I want to include the current year in, as well as the following year.

For example:

```
<a href="https://www.fakesite.com/search.aspx?&amp;StartDate=12/10/2016&amp;EndDate=12/25/2017">2016 to 2017</a>
```

Instead of manually having to maintain the link, I would like to make the current year and future year dynamically print.

Can anyone tell me the best way to accomplish this?  The page is PHP, so I wasn't sure if there's a easy way with PHP or jQuery, or something else.

I already tried `<?php echo date("Y"); ?>` and it didn't work on the front end (it was blank in the spot I was trying to get 2016 to display).

Comment: `echo date("Y");` should absolutely work!

Answer (score 1):

For both year

```
<?php
$current= new \DateTime();
$future = new \DateTime('+ 1 years');
?>
```

or you can use it with one line

```
$current = (new DateTime)->format("Y");
```

.

```
<a href="https://www.fakesite.com/search.aspx?&amp;StartDate=<?php echo $current->format('m/d/Y'); ?>&amp;EndDate=<?php echo $future->format('m/d/Y'); ?>"><?php echo $current->format('Y')." to ".$future ->format('Y');?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like:

```
<?php
$year = date("Y");
$nextYear = $year + 1;
echo <<< LOL
<a href="https://www.fakesite.com/search.aspx?StartDate=12/10/$year&EndDate=12/25/$nextYear">$year to $nextYear</a>
LOL;
?>
```